# Where to Create / Get / Cache the ViewModels?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, viewmodel

First off, I'm new to MVVM, so please help me out on this :)

Suppose I have multiple views in my app. In my case, I have an editor view, and a browser view.
Both of them have to work with a viewmodel of a "node" I'm editing.

So where does the viewmodel actually get created ?

Suppose the Editor is told to edit a certain node - It could create a new "NodeViewModel" and work with that. But at the same time, there's a NodeBrowserView, which allows people to shortcut-select a different node.
Basicly - I need the EditorView to work with the same ViewModel as the BrowserView, so I need a generic "GetViewModelfor(X)" method.

So how is this supposed to work ? :)

Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

Both your *editor* view and *browser* view should operate on some kind of `NodeViewModel`. You shouldn't need separate view models just for the different view scenario.

Now, can you edit *not-yet-shown-to-user* node? If no (as in, user decides what is edited), view models should be created at the very first time their content needs to be presented to user. In most cases this would in some *browser/details views*, so that user can select element and **then** chose to edit it.

**Edit**:

Regarding your comment. `NodeViewModel` should be provided for *editor view*.

The *providing* part can be done for example via [constructor injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) or by setting view's data context manually. For example, when user browses all nodes in the *browser view*, he can double click on the list item and *editor view* will pop-up:

```
// this will probably be done in response to event
private void ListItemDoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NodeViewModel currentItem = // extract current list item
    EditorView editorView = new EditorView(currentItem);
    editorView.Show();
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to avoid this kind of strong coupling between `CompositeView` and `EditorView` you can always use events, however it's not always necessary.

One more thing I was thinking of in terms of design would be adding extra view model, call it `NodesListViewModel`. How the program flow might look like:

1. At application startup, get your nodes (be it from DB, file, service, anything)
2. Create instance of `NodeListViewModel` which takes dependency on `IList<Node>` (list of node entities)
3. `NodeListViewModel` will build and expose collection of `NodeViewModel` elements
4. Create instance of your main program window, which uses composite view. It needs `NodeListViewModel` as its data context.
5. Whenever user decides he needs to edit item, it's all ready. Browser has a list of all `NodeViewModels`, it can easily pick up current and pass it to dedicated view.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you're spot-on.
The NodeViewModel needs to be created when it's first-used, but when another view needs it I need that view to use the same viewmodel.
So my question is - in the MVVM pattern, where does the creation/caching of the viewmodel actually happen ?
Once the Editor decides it's going to edit a certain node, it needs a NodeViewModel for that node. If the CompositionBrowser was having fun with that node already, the Editor needs to use the same NodeViewModel as the CompositionBrowser. So where do they both get the viewmodel ?

Comment: @IUsedToBeAPygmy: it's rather common communication related scenario, see my edit.

Comment: Another option is to have the EditorView instead specified as a `DataTemplate` for the view model type in a resources and pop-open a new Window with the view model as the Content. The rest will be automagic.

Answer (score 0):

In cases like this I prefer to use a single main view model and have a "current item" that the view connects to instead.  This is a lot easier to do instead of passing / creating new view models around each time a user clicks a different node / grid row / etc.  I really see no need to a separate view model either when the same operations can be achieved in the overall view model.  It reduces complexity and reduces the change of creating objects (view models) and leaving them hanging around because a reference to them was not released until the application is closed.